# Best Practices For Silverlight Localization?

Tags: silverlight, localization

Does anyone have any best practices or experience of localization in Silverlight. [MSDN recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd882554(VS.95).aspx) binding the resource to the XAML, but the result is pretty messy:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Resource1.HelloText, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings }}"/>
```

A page of that is going to make the XAML unreadable!

Any shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a similar but more complex question a while back ([silverlight paramterised resource values for internationalisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044699/silverlight-paramterised-resource-values-for-internationalisation))

The example given on MSDN is really insufficient for serious localization, it assumes every string is entirely present and has no parameters, the reality is you will have values you wish to embed within the string but need placeholder to mark the location of that variable in the string so a translator can move the marker as they translate.

You can achieve a more advanced mechanism by implementing multi-binding yourself into silverlight - Colin Eberhardt did a nice implementation ([silverlight multibindings how to attached mutiple bindings to a single property](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/06/silverlight-multibindings-how-to-attached-mutiple-bindings-to-a-single-property/)) - adjusted a bit and combined with a MultiValue Converter you can perform multiple bindings, allowing the first binding to be to the language file, and subsequent bindings to be to the parameters to be embedded.

It's quite a pain but the localization story is just noticably lacking - even chatting at the PDC09 over silverlight 3 / 4 there is really not a great route at present in place - if WPF multibinding makes it across to SL4 that makes it slightly easier, but I havn't seen a good alternative implementation as yet except for people outputting all the strings from the ViewModel - which seems wrong form the 'designers' perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that Microsoft recommendation for Silverlight (and WPF and Windows Phone) localization is very rudimentary. It has several issues. Most important are

1. It is hard to edit main maintain two separate files: XAML and RESX
2. Your loose great part of string content when you move it from XAML to RESX
3. XAML becomes much harder to read and maintain

The reason for this is that Microsoft tools such as Visual Studio, **does not** provide any way to localize XAML. An easy solition here is the localize XAML and include the localized XAML along with localized RESX into satellite assembly files.

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
```

is much easier to view, edit and maintain than

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Resource1.HelloText, Source={StaticResource LocalizedString }}"/>

+

  <data name="LocalizedString" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Hello World</value>
  </data>
```

What you need to do is to keep hard coding string into XAML and localize the XAML itself. This gets very difficult without a good tool. This is why I recommend you to use a localization tool that can locize XAML. This alone is not enought because if you have localized XAML you still need to compile them into satellite asembly file and finally include the satellite inside your XAP file.

You need to have a tool that can localize RESX and XAML and also compile localized satellite assembly files. There are somes tool that can do that (for example Sisulizer).

If you want to use only Visual Studio then you have to stick with the best practices by Microsoft.