# DataBinding using helper class in Silverlight 4 Error

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I am new to the whole Silverlight thing. And got a problem

I have a class derrived from Binding the Localizer, which is declared like this:

```
public class Localizer : Binding
{
    public Localizer()
    {
    }

    private string _key;

    /// <summary>
    /// Localization key manager.
    /// </summary>
    public string Key
    {
        get { return _key; }
        set
        {
            _key = value;

            Source = LocalizationHelper.Current;
            Path = new PropertyPath("Translations["+_key+"]");
        }
    }
}
```

When I am using it in the XAML page

```
<p:BasePage x:Class="Project.Pages.Desktop"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
xmlns:h="clr-namespace:Project.Helpers">   

<TextBlock Controls:DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{h:Localizer Key=UI_DSKTP_NAME}"/>
```

I got an error

```
Type 'h:Localizer' is used like a markup extension but does not derive from MarkupExtension.
```

This error allow the project to compile, and binding works, but it is anoying.
Can you help me resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of {Binding} and other such markup extensions are hard-wired into the Xaml parser.  You cannot "roll your own".

It seems to me that you are attempting to create a Localisation framework in you Silverlight app.  See answers to this question [Best Practices For Silverlight Localization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102404/best-practices-for-silverlight-localization).